# XMLHttpRequest() returning 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following javascript which runs when an image is clicked:

```
function dateBack () {
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("hell").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("hell").innerHTML = httpRequest.readyState;
                    document.getElementById("hell").innerHTML = httpRequest.status;
                    
                }
            };
            httpRequest.open('POST', 'subtractDay.php?depDate=sal', true)
        }
```

and the subtractDay.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
    $depDate = $_REQUEST["depDate"];
    echo $depDate;
?>
```

The code has  been edited slightly from my original code for simplicity sake.
When I click the image, the element with id "hell" gets the value of 0 which means that the request was not initialized.
The file subtractDate.php can be accessed from the same server as the file with the javascript code. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it missing `.send()`

```
httpRequest.open('POST', 'subtractDay.php?depDate=sal', true)
httpRequest.send(null);
```